# How to load react component from an external service inside a React app via AJAX

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, reactjs, microservices

What are the best practices associated with loading/inserting and running  React components from an external service in an existing React application via AJAX.

I have a main React app and want to load various React components (from external services) via AJAX. How could this be done?

Is this feasible at all? If not what is the way to go about it?

Can this work with webpack?

Answer (score 3):

Consider using this library by @thejameskyle  https://github.com/thejameskyle/react-loadable It acts as a lazy loader for your react components including remote ones

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried it out and it works perfectly for react components in React app, but not for the external service - what I did was I loaded the react component code from the external service using AJAX. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I currently haven't tried out using that formula. But if it works should be ok. you could share some code to see how you are doing it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Do we use `import` or `fetch` to get the external javascript file?

Answer (score 0):

You can use: https://github.com/faceyspacey/react-universal-component and load the component code as a string (which is what I assume you're doing if you're talking about retrieving it over "ajax"), evaluate it, and return it from the `asyncComponent` function as a promise, or pass it to a callback passed to the function. It's like React Loadable, but doesn't need to work strictly with async imports. Check the docs.

Comment: I like the approach and your library. Is there a demo for consuming an externally/CDN hosted React component ?

Answer (score 0):

Micro apps fit this niche perfectly. The concept is to bundle your component as a standalone bundle and then load it into your application on demand from a url. There are several approaches you can take to accomplish this. There is a [higher-order component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@schalltech/honeycomb-react-microapp) that does this for you. All that is needed is to import the hoc and then pass it a json config that identifies the micro app you want to lazy load into your application.

```
<MicroApp
       config={{
         View: {
           Name: 'redbox-demo',
           Scope: 'beekeeper',
           Version: 'latest'
         }
       }}
     />
```

Using the configuration above will load this [movie browsing](https://microapp.host/beekeeper/redboxdemo/) micro app directly into your host application.

You can find further reading on how it works and source code here.

https://github.com/Schalltech/honeycomb-marketplace